# Include polygon ID when extracting raster values to polygons in R

Tags: r

I followed [How do I extract raster values from polygon data then join into spatial data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333473/how-do-i-extract-raster-values-from-polygon-data-then-join-into-spatial-data-fra) (which was helpful) to create a matrix (then data frame) of mean raster values to a polygon. The problem now is that I want to know which polygon is which. My SpatialPolygonsDataFrame has an ID value in `p$Block_ID`. Is there a way to bring that over in the `extract()` code?

Alternatively, does the `extract()` function report output in the order it was input (that would make sense)? i.e. the order of `p$Block_ID` will be preserved in the output? I looked through the documentation and it was not clear one way or the other. If so it is easy enough to add an ID column to the `extract()` output.

Here is my generalized code for reference. NOTE note reproducible because I don't think it really needs to be at this point. Where r is a raster and p in the polygons

```
extract(r, p, small = TRUE, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE, df = TRUE, nl = 1)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are returned in order, as one would expect in R, and as stated in the manual (`?extract`): *The order of the returned values corresponds to the order of object y*

Thus you can do (reproducible example from `?extract`)

```
e <- extract(r, p)
ee <- data.frame(ID=p$Block_ID, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get R. Hijmans answer working for me. I found that this works.

```
e = extract(r, p)
e$ID = as.factor(e$ID)
levels(e$ID) = levels(p$Block_ID)
```